# Why does UIUserInterfaceStyle require iOS12 when Dark Mode was introduced in iOS13?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm confused about this. My app is supposed to support iOS 11.0+.

This is how I would check if the phone is capable of displaying the DarkMode and is in DarkMode.

```
    func isDarkMode() -> Bool {
        if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
            switch traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle {
            case .light, .unspecified:
                return false
            case .dark:
                return true
            @unknown default:
                return false
            }
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            return false
        }
    }
```

But then I realised something is not right, because the DarkMode was only introduced in iOS 13.0.  Why were .dark and .light introduced by Apple already via traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle in iOS12.0 ?

```
@available(iOS 12.0, *)
public enum UIUserInterfaceStyle : Int {

    
    case unspecified = 0

    case light = 1

    case dark = 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple often sneaks a feature unannounced into an earlier system. That way, they only have to throw a feature switch to "turn on" the feature that's already there. This is an example of that. The user interface style was actually introduced in iOS 12, but it does nothing until iOS 13.

So your code will run harmlessly in iOS 12. But it would probably be more intentful to change the availability setting to iOS 13.